# Is an electric dryer's vent pipe a fire hazard when routed through the floor?

Tags: venting

I will be venting my electric clothes dryer through a pre-cut hole in the floor.  It will be vented using flexible, foil type tubing and traveling a short distance to an exhaust on the side of my home.  My concern is how hot the dryer venting may get that is almost touching the bare wood hole in the floor.  I haven't found a collar that would fit around the 4 inch tubing and fit the hole, which is around 5 inches.  Could I line the hole with a silver foil duct tape used for HVAC jobs, etc. to protect it against the heat?  Suggestions?

Comment: A dryer will destroy the clothing inside before it gets hot enough to damage the wood floor.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a concern. Dryer exhaust might hit 200 degrees, but most have thermal fuses far below that. You'd need twice that and then some to start a fire. Heck, many dryers are vented through cheap vinyl hose. If it was a concern building codes would require double-wall flues akin to those used for gas appliance exhaust.

I do recommend against the lightweight foil hose, though. It really accumulates lint. Use semi-rigid aluminum pipe at least ([example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-8-ft-Semi-Rigid-Dryer-Duct-WX08X10075DS/202214660)). Its ridges are much smaller and it's less likely to close up on itself in a bend.

You may have heard of the risk of not cleaning the lint filter. This can result in reduced airflow and heat accumulation, but any fire is likely to begin *in* the dryer in this case. [More on that](https://www.laundry-alternative.com/how-to-prevent-clothes-dryer-fires/)

Comment: I do agree but use solid pipe under the floor like isherwood + suggests flex on top and clean the lint that makes it through regularly, lint fires are a major cause of dryer fires even if the lint trap is cleaned, no worries on the heat of the pipe in normal operation as far as the wood is concerned. Also if you see lint whiskers restating to build on the outside vent it is a good time to clean out the pipe.

Comment: I assumed that the duct would need to be pulled and that rigid pipe wouldn't work, but definitely use wherever possible.

Comment: I use the thin wall "rigid" pipe all the time with a 4 piece adjustable 90, blast the output side of a shop vac down the pipe and because it is smooth all the lint ends up out side but the flex inside still needs to be cleaned because of all the ridges .